# How can I start a web app when I open my Tizen TV?

Tags: tizen-tv

I have a web app for a Tizen TV. How can I make so that the app starts when the TV opens ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Solution,

1.Take the .wgt file and upload in to Server and add sssp_config.xml.

2.In sssp_config.xml,add your wgt name and version of the app.

Code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget>
<ver>Your Version Number</ver>
<size>80</size>
<widgetname>Project name</widgetname>
</widget>
```

3.Go to tizen tv,tab on URl setting button.

4.Enter your Server Address till the folder.

Example: localhost/8080/tizen(Folder contain .wgt file)

5.Finally , Tap on URL Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is as described a Web Application:

Your app needs to be uploaded somewhere in form of a .wgt archive. There must also be an sssp_config.xml, which tells the display what widget to use as well as some basic settings, as soon as the display connects to wherever you uploaded the .wgt as well as the .xml.

In the display settings you need to turn off "choose source automatically" and choose URL launcher as source. Also set it as the default option in the display menu. Finally in the URL launcher settings you need to set the URL to your .wgt/.xml, so that the display can download the app.

From what I've seen this will work if you have your application running when the display is going into standby. On startup it will connect to the adress by default, update the app if the sssp_config.xml dictates so and then launch the app.

I have however not found an option to reliably force the usage of the URL launcher if the source has been changed somehow.

Comment: We have had the same problem and held corespondence with SAMSUNG regarding this. Afaik there is no such option once the source has changed. The only way we are aware of to this remotely is to then use MDC.